# Convert decimal into binary, octal, and hexadecimal?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to convert a variable, which will always be a number, into binary, octal, and hex with Ruby.

The code I have at this point is:

```
def convert(number)
  puts "#{number} in decimal is"
  puts "#{number.to_s(2)} in binary"
  puts "#{number.to_s(8)} in octal"
  puts "#{number.to_s(16)} in hexadecimal"
end
```

and so far the output is:

```
2 in decimal is
10 in binary
2 in octal
2 in hexadecimal
```

The first two lines run fine, but after that it is ignoring the conversion command and just putting the variable in. Does anyone have any idea what it is I am missing?

Comment: Downvote because of the trivial problem in the original question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the fact that `2` is... `2` in base 8, 16, or any base greater than 2. Try `convert(42)` for fun.